# .NET api for document screenshot?

Tags: .net, ms-office, ole

I'd like to find or build a library/dll to generate images/screenshots of Office and other documents *in the background* (i.e. without explicitly launching the app).

As this post describes, the OLE api allowed creating a container which references an external file, and then extracting an image of the referenced file:

[How to extract metafile from TOleContainer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861008/how-to-extract-metafile-from-tolecontainer)

Is there an equivalent api in .NET?

Comment: OLE is dinosaur, .NET has no support for it whatsoever.

Comment: Yes, I know, hence my question :-)

Comment: Then you probably already know about Microsoft.Office.Interop as well.  Hard to guess if it is appropriate, OLE and screenshots are a strange combination.

Comment: Hadn't heard of it; it's a scripting API for Office apps? A quick look didn't turn up any to-image rendering apis...

Answer (score 0):

Not an api but here is a component. You can create documents to images with this one. It works with both C# and VB.NET
http://miracle00.weebly.com/4/post/2012/4/convert-word-document-to-image-with-c-vbnet.html

For the background working, you can search for "threads" in google and SO, you will find many examples.