# Extract bitmap from TOleContainer?

Tags: delphi, bitmap, containers, extract, ole

I'm trying to extract bitmap from `TOleContainer` using the IDataObject's GetData method.

```
 OleContainer1.CreateObject('Paint.Picture', false);
 OleContainer1.OleObjectInterface.QueryInterface(IDataObject, DataObject);
```

EnumFormatEtc with `DATADIR_GET` on DataObject returns the following:

```
 cfFormat, ptd, dwAspect, lIndex, tymed

 CF_METAFILEPICT, nil, DVASPECT_CONTENT, -1, TYMED_MFPICT
 CF_DIB, nil, DVASPECT_CONTENT, -1, TYMED_HGLOBAL or TYMED_ISTREAM
 CF_BITMAP, nil, DVASPECT_CONTENT, -1, TYMED_HGLOBAL
```

But when I do:

```
FormatEtc.cfFormat := CF_BITMAP;
FormatEtc.ptd := nil;
FormatEtc.dwAspect := DVASPECT_CONTENT;
FormatEtc.lIndex := -1;
FormatEtc.tymed := TYMED_HGLOBAL;

OleCheck(DataObject.GetData(FormatEtc, StorageMedium));
```

I'm getting **Invalid FORMATETC stucture** error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to replace media type from `TYMED_HGLOBAL` to `TYMED_GDI` as suggested in [`this thread`](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/bc/272674.html).

Comment: I've already tried that. Same error.

Comment: Another way of doing it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861008/how-to-extract-metafile-from-tolecontainer

Answer (score 1):

I do the same thing you are trying to do by using the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861008/how-to-extract-metafile-from-tolecontainer).  In my case, I found it best to do the following, which uses the `DrawOleOnBmp()` in the provided link:

```
oleMain.UpdateObject;
if oleMain.OleObjectInterface = nil then
  raise Exception.Create('OLE Container is empty.');
DrawOleOnBmp(oleMain.OleObjectInterface, imgMain.Bitmap);
imgMain.Bitmap.SaveToFile('Filename.bmp');
```

Where `oleMain` is a `TOleContainer`, and `imgMain` is a `TImage32`.  Both are visible on the form...

For convenience, here is the method from the link, written by @MarkElder:

```
{
  DrawOleOnBmp
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Take a OleObject and draw it to a bitmap canvas.  The bitmap will be sized
  to match the normal size of the OLE Object.
}
procedure DrawOleOnBmp(Ole: IOleObject; Bmp: TBitmap32);
var
  ViewObject2: IViewObject2;
  ViewSize: TPoint;
  AdjustedSize: TPoint;
  DC: HDC;
  R: TRect;
begin
  if Succeeded(Ole.QueryInterface(IViewObject2, ViewObject2)) then
  begin
    ViewObject2.GetExtent(DVASPECT_CONTENT, -1, nil, ViewSize);

    DC := GetDC(0);
    AdjustedSize.X := MulDiv(ViewSize.X, GetDeviceCaps(DC, LOGPIXELSX), 2540);
    AdjustedSize.Y := MulDiv(ViewSize.Y, GetDeviceCaps(DC, LOGPIXELSY), 2540);
    ReleaseDC(0, DC);

    Bmp.Height := AdjustedSize.Y;
    Bmp.Width := AdjustedSize.X;

    Bmp.FillRect(0, 0, Bmp.Width, Bmp.Height, clWhite);

    SetRect(R, 0, 0, Bmp.Width, Bmp.Height);

    OleDraw(Ole, DVASPECT_CONTENT, Bmp.Canvas.Handle, R);
  end
  else
  begin
    raise Exception.Create('Could not get the IViewObject2 interfact on the OleObject');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for you input. I suppose this would work, but for one thing, do you happen to know what is the cause of `GetData` failure? Seems it has to do with `TYMED_HGLOBAL`, as when I change `CF_BITMAP` to `CF_DIB` and `TYMED_HGLOBAL` to `TYMED_ISTREAM` then I am able to retrieve the data successfully. For another, I would also like to write the data back and this is only possible with `IDataObject` interface, isn't it?

Comment: I haven't played that much with the `TOleContainer`, so I'm no expert with using the `IDataObject` interface.  But last July I was trying to convert RTF documents to another format.  Many of them contained OLE objects.  I only saw the "Invalid FORMATETC stucture" when the OLE server wasn't installed on my computer for one of the OLE objects.  If your error is caused from the same issue (missing OLE server), then there is nothing you can do with code to eliminate the error.  The OLE server must be present to parse the OLE data and render it.